# imprimir datos de array

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

el problema que tengo es que quiero imprimir unos datos en una grafica , tengo el canvas y las consultas ya echas pero no sé como imprimir los valores en la grafica específicamente en el data[], puse un vardumb y las consultas si estas jalando la información, para la impresión de datos yo se que tengo que hacer uso de un array o de pasar la información a un json y luego mandársela a la grafica pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer eso y la razón por la que no los imprimo directamente es por que tengo que imprimir los datos que sean de la misma `numero departe`    `calendario` y mismo `proveedor` por lo que deja de ser un solo registro.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 

<?php

 include ("conexion_bd.php");

 $consulta = $_GET['id_registro'];  //creo una variable que trae el id_registro
// $prov=$_GET['nombre_proveedor'];



 $sql1= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id_registro, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, nombre_proveedor, numero_parte, calendario FROM act WHERE id_registro = $consulta");  //selecciono los campos necesarios de la tabla con el id_registro

 if ($sql1){
     $dat1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
 }else {
     echo "error: " . $query . "<br>" .mysqli_error($conexion);
 

 }

 $proveedor= $dat1['nombre_proveedor'];
 $parte= $dat1['numero_parte'];
 $calendario= $dat1['calendario'];

 $sql= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id_registro, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, nombre_proveedor, numero_parte, calendario FROM act WHERE nombre_proveedor = '$proveedor' AND calendario = '$calendario' AND numero_parte ='$parte'");  //selecciono los campos necesarios de la tabla con el id_registro

 /*if ($sql){
    $dat2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
}else {
    echo "error: " . $query . "<br>" .mysqli_error($conexion);

}*/
?>


<?php
while($dat=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    var_dump($dat1);
 $t1= $dat['t1'];      //creo vrables guardando los datos consultados 
 $t2= $dat['t2'];
 $t3= $dat['t3'];
 $t4= $dat['t4'];
 $t5= $dat['t5'];
 $id= $dat['id_registro'];

 //$proveedor= $dat['nombre_proveedor'];
 //$parte= $dat['numero_parte'];
 //$calendario= $dat['calendario'];

 $resultado = $t1 + $t2 + $t3 + $t4 + $t5;   

 if($t1>=$t2 && $t1>=$t3 && $t1>=$t4 && $t1>=$t5) 
  {
 $maximo = $t1;
 }elseif ($t2>=$t1 && $t2>=$t3 && $t2>=$t4 && $t2>=$t5)
 {
     $maximo = $t2;
 }elseif ($t3>=$t1 && $t3>=$t2 && $t3>=$t4 && $t3>=$t5)
 {
     $maximo = $t3;
 }elseif ($t4>=$t1 && $t4>=$t2 && $t4>=$t3 && $t4>=$t5)
 {
     $maximo=$t4;
 }elseif ($t5>=$t1 && $t5>=$t2 && $t5>=$t3 && $t5>=$t4)
 {
     $maximo=$t5;
 }
  
     
     $promedio = $resultado/5; 
 ?>
 <?php 
 if($t1<=$t2 && $t1<=$t3 && $t1<=$t4 && $t1<=$t5)  
 {
     $minimo = $t1;
 }elseif ($t2<=$t1 && $t2<=$t3 && $t2<=$t4 && $t2<=$t5)
 {
     $minimo = $t2;
 }elseif ($t3<=$t1 && $t3<=$t2 && $t3<=$t4 && $t3<=$t5)
 {
     $minimo = $t3;
 }elseif ($t4<=$t1 && $t4<=$t2 && $t4<=$t3 && $t4<=$t5)
 {
     $minimo=$t4;
 }elseif ($t5<=$t1 && $t5<=$t2 && $t5<=$t3 && $t5<=$t4)
 {
     $minimo=$t5;
 }
?>



<div class="chart-container">
<canvas id= "graf"></canvas>


    <?php
}
?>


<?php

$stringDatos = "";

$arrayDataSets = "[{type: 'bar', 'label': 'CYCLE TIME', data:[ ";

while($datos = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){

                $stringDatos .= "$datos[t1],[t2],[t3],[t4],[t5]";

}

// Elimina la última coma

$stringDatos = substr($stringDatos, 0, -1);


$arrayDataSets .= $stringDatos . "]}";

$arrayDataSets .= ", {type: 'line', 'label': 'MAXIMO', data:[";

 

// Borramos la cadena anterior

$stringDatos = "";

while($datos = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){

      $stringDatos .= "$datos[t1],";

}

// Elimina la última coma

$stringDatos = substr($stringDatos, 0, -1);

$arrayDataSets .= $stringDatos . "]}";

$arrayDataSets .= ", {type: 'line', 'label': 'MINIMO', data:[";

 

// Borramos la cadena anterior

$stringDatos = "";

while($datos = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){

                $stringDatos .= "$datos[t2],";

}

// Elimina la última coma

$stringDatos = substr($stringDatos, 0, -1);


$arrayDataSets .= $stringDatos . "]}";

$arrayDataSets .= "]";


?>

<script type="text/javascript">

                var mixedChart = new Chart(graf, {

    data: {

        datasets: <?php echo $arrayDataSets; ?>,

        labels: ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'AVERAGE']

    },

    options: {}

});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['usuarios'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['usuarios']['tipo'] != "Admin") {
        header('Location: ../Usuario/usuario.php'); 
    } 
} else {
         header('Location: ../../index.php');
}

$host='localhost'; 
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'thanks';

try{
    $pdo = new  PDO("mysql:host=localhost;database=$database", $username, $password);
    
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch (PDOExeption $e){

    die("ERROR: could not connect. ".  $e->getMessage());
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>THANKS Digital</title>
    <link style="width:30px;" rel="shortcut icon" href="img/Pr.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/panel-act4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu-opciones2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/view-activity3.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/i.css">
    
</head>


<?php

$consulta = $_GET['id_registro'];  //creo una variable que trae el id_registro
// $prov=$_GET['nombre_proveedor'];

 $sql1= "SELECT * FROM thanks.act WHERE id_registro = $consulta";  //selecciono los campos necesarios de la tabla con el id_registro
 $result1 = $pdo->query($sql1);
 while ($row1 = $result1->fetch()){
 $proveedor= $row1['nombre_proveedor'];
 $parte= $row1['numero_parte'];
 $calendario= $row1['calendario'];
 }
try {
    // $sql= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id_registro, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, nombre_proveedor, numero_parte, calendario FROM act WHERE nombre_proveedor = '$proveedor' AND calendario = '$calendario' AND numero_parte ='$parte'");  //selecciono los campos necesarios de la tabla con el id_registro

    $sql = "SELECT * from thanks.act WHERE nombre_proveedor = '$proveedor' AND calendario = '$calendario' AND numero_parte ='$parte'"; 
     $result = $pdo->query($sql);
         if($result->rowCount()>0){
           $t1 = array();                       //aqui se crean los arrays
           $t2 = array();
           $t3 = array();
           $t4 = array();
           $t5 = array();

              while ($row = $result->fetch()){
                 $t1[] = $row["t1"];
                 $t2[] = $row["t2"];                //aqui recorre el array llenandolo con datos de la BD 
                 $t3[] = $row["t3"];
                 $t4[] = $row["t4"];
                 $t5[] = $row["t5"];

        }unset($result); 

    } else {
            echo "no records matching" ; 
    }
}catch (PDOExeption $e){
    die ("ERROR: could not able to execute $sql. ". $e->getMessage());
} 

unset($pdo);
?>
<!-- //setup Block  -->
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"</script>

<script> 

console.log (<?php echo json_encode($t1); ?>)
console.log (<?php echo json_encode($t2); ?>)
console.log (<?php echo json_encode($t3); ?>)
console.log (<?php echo json_encode($t4); ?>)
console.log (<?php echo json_encode($t5); ?>)
const t1 = <?php echo json_encode($t1); ?>              //pasamos los datos a json
const t2 = <?php echo json_encode($t2); ?> 
const t3 = <?php echo json_encode($t3); ?> 
const t4 = <?php echo json_encode($t4); ?> 
const t5 = <?php echo json_encode($t5); ?> 
const data = {
labels: ['REGISTRO 1', 'REGISTRO 2', 'REGISTRO 3', 'REGISTRO 4', 'REGISTRO 5', 'REGISTRO 6'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 't1',
            data: t1,           //en este data se impirmen los datos
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',         //el color de las graficas
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },{
            label: 't2',
            data: t2,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },{
            label: 't3',
            data: t3,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },{
            label: 't4',
            data: t4,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },{
            label: 't5',
            data: t5,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        } 
        
        
        ]
    };
//     const actions = [    //ese codigo es para agregar en la grafica un boton para agregar datos.
//         {
//     name: 'Add Data',
//     handler(chart) {
//       const data = chart.data;
//       if (data.datasets.length > 0) {
//         data.labels = Utils.months({count: data.labels.length + 1});

//         for (var index = 0; index < data.datasets.length; ++index) {
//           data.datasets[index].data.push(Utils.rand(-100, 100));
//         }

//         chart.update();
//       }
//     }
//   }

//     ];

    const data2 = {
labels: ['Average'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Average',
            data: t1,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]};
//config Block 

const config  = {

        type :'bar',
        data, 
        options: {
            scales: {
                y:{ 
                    beginAtZero: true 
                }
            }
        }
};



//Render Block
const myChart = new Chart (document.getElementById('myChart'),config);  //aqui carga la grafica y la imprime en pantalla
```